# Convert a cell separated values into Semi-colon separated in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to convert the excel file having value separated per cell into semi-colon separated values.

How is it possible to be done in Microsoft Excel

Sample

Cell-separated format

[image]

to Semi-colon separated format

[image]

Comment: Yo want your cells and values to have semi-colons or do you want a csv file with semi-colon as separator?

Comment: the file needs to be csv file and format of content should be converted to semi-colon separated

Comment: semi colon as separator

Comment: So your file is a "normal" Excel file?

Comment: correct. a normal one

Answer (score 1):

If you save your file as csv, it will use your regional settings to either set this as , or ;. So changing your regional settings then saving the file will work.

Additionally, you can use the following trick to make most programs recognize the delimiter.

Open the .csv file with a text editor, such as notepad.
On the first line press enter to create a new line. Now type `sep=,` where , is the character used to separate values.

Comment: nothing's changed after doing this..

Comment: You must first change the regional settings, then save the file. just changing the regional settings are not magically changing all files on your computer.

Comment: Hi again, i did what you instructed, I sav the file in CSV first, then when I opened in notepa++, yet it is already showing in semi-colon separated, but when I open in excel, it is not, cell separated

Comment: if it shows up in notepad++ with ; separated, then add a row at the top, saying sep=; and save that. Now excel will understand it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the default delimiter.

In Windows 10, select Start -> Control Panel -> Region -> Additional Settings -> List Separator, then update ',' to  ';' and press Enter to apply.

If using Windows 7, select Start -> Control Panel -> Regional and Language Options -> Additional Settings -> List Separator, then update ',' to ';' and press Enter to apply.

CVS generate files now use ";" separator instead of ",".

Comment: nothing's changed after doing this

Comment: Have you save the Excel Book as CSV file? If so, I guess you still open the file in Microsoft Excel, that's why nothing changes there. You can open the file with Notepad or any other Text Editor. You will see the differences.

Comment: should I restart computer? i change the list separator to , to ; but when I open in notepad, the separator is still ,

Comment: No, you don't need to do that. It should be effective immediately. Just double check if the List Separator updated to ";".

Comment: Hi again, i did what you instructed, I sav the file in CSV first, then when I opened in notepa++, yet it is already showing in semi-colon separated, but when I open in excel, it is not, cell separated